Why is the future perfect used in "This latest setback will have done nothing to quell the growing doubts about the future of the club."?
This is a sample sentence from Cambridge dictionary for the headword "quell".

This latest setback will have done nothing to quell the growing doubts about the future of the club.

It was somewhat surprising to me that the future perfect tense was used in this sentence as it starts off with something that takes place in the past, namely "latest setback", nevertheless while writing this post I think I caught on as to why this sentence is actually correct.
Question: Is the future perfect tense used because it actually refers to the effects of the setback that will be felt in the future and they will do nothing to quell the doubts about the future of the club?

Yes. Way in the future, we can look back and say it did nothing to quell doubts.

Yes, but remember that it's important to ask not just Is it correct? but also What does it mean? You could also say This latest setback will do nothing to quell... Both tenses are correct, but they don't mean the same.

The sought-for effect already didn't happen - that fact hasn't been formally established yet, but it will be found not to have happened at some future time.

perhaps worth noting: the sample sentence reads as slightly flowery to me, like phrasing a politician or a journalist might use.  if someone said this to me, and the club in question were e.g. a chess club, i might think they're taking it a bit too seriously.

As an American, this use of the future perfect sounds very British to me. Although there are related usages that would sound natural to me, but the British dialect is much more prone to talk this way, I think.

@FumbleFingers I think your comment would be the best answer if it were posted as an answer.

We normally use future perfect to predict something that will happen in the future, but we can also use it to state an opinion about something that has probably already happened. here is a description of it from the BBC web site.
For example, you could say:

There's no point in calling John: he will have left the office already.

You don't know that John has left the office: you are simply expressing an opinion that this is probably currently the case.

This latest setback will have done nothing to quell the growing doubts about the future of the club.

Taken literally, the writer is suggesting the the setback has probably done nothing yet to quell... etc. This is a typical example of understatement: what the writer implies is that the setback has probably already increased doubts about the future of the club.

While it's true that "will have" is sometimes used in this way to refer to something that has probably already happened, I don't think that's the intent in the OP's example sentence. (Instead, I think FumbleFingers' comment is on target.)

@LarsH: I think this answer is effectively saying the same thing as my comment - it's just that I baldly asserted that it already hadn't happened, where JavaLatte says it probably didn't happen. That's a sliver of difference that doesn't really mean anything - it's just that my perspective allows for a very succinct summary of the reason for the superficially unusual choice of verb tense.

Like @GlennWillen above, I hear this much more in UK English than in US English. Notice that the sentence in the question is from the Cambridge dictionary, and the Q&A page linked in this answer is from the BBC!


This latest setback will have done nothing to quell the growing doubts ...

Compare this with will do nothing:
This latest setback will do nothing to quell the growing doubts...
The latter simply predicts an absence of effects from the setback.
In the will have done version, someone looking back from the verdict time will see the actual absence of effect.  Compare these two:
He will not complete the task.
He will not have completed the task (by the deadline).
The second one has this component of deadline.

This use of modal will with the present perfect expresses something other than a declaration of fact; it expresses a strong conviction on the part of the speaker that the utterance is true.
John will have left the office by now expresses greater conviction  than John must have left the office by now.

This latest setback will have done nothing to quell the growing doubts about the future of the club.

The speaker is convinced that the doubts will continue to grow despite the latest setback.  And the reason the speaker can be convinced is that the latest setback is more of the same sort of thing that caused the doubts in the first place. It is snarky, a form of vacuous irony that boils down to "This setback won't help things any."
Compare:

This latest sex-trafficking allegation will have done nothing to quell the growing doubts about the vicar's moral integrity.

Duh.
